# How to set the Explosion Power in the config?

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to set the **float explosionPower** to 10F in the **config** so I can easily change it through the plugin. How do I do this?

Code:

```
@EventHandler
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onPlayerInteractBlock(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    float explosionPower = 10F;
    if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.DIAMOND_SWORD) {
    player.getWorld().strikeLightning(player.getTargetBlock(null, 50).getLocation());
    player.getWorld().createExplosion(player.getTargetBlock(null, 50).getLocation(), explosionPower);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the value of the float in the config via:

```
float explosionPower = this.getConfig.getFloat("path");
```

with path being where it is in the config, so with the above code, in the config it would look like this:

```
path: 10
```

`path` should be changed to something like `power`, or `explosionPower`.

You would most likely want to do this in your main file. Also, you don't have to use `float literal`, so instead of putting `10.0f`, you could just use `10`, and instead of `9.2f`, you could just use `9.2`. Here's an example with your code:

```
@EventHandler
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onPlayerInteractBlock(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    float explosionPower = this.getConfig.getFloat("power"); //this is what we changed
    if(player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.DIAMOND_SWORD) {
        player.getWorld().strikeLightning(player.getTargetBlock(null, 50).getLocation());
        player.getWorld().createExplosion(player.getTargetBlock(null, 50).getLocation(), explosionPower);
    }
}
```

whereas, with the code above, the config would look like:

```
power: 10
```

Also, To make your code better, here is a re-done version of it:

```
@EventHandler
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onPlayerInteractBlock(PlayerInteractEvent event){
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if (player.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD)){
        float explosionPower = this.getConfig.getFloat("power");
        player.getWorld().strikeLightning(player.getTargetBlock(null, 50).getLocation());
        player.getWorld().createExplosion(player.getTargetBlock(null, 50).getLocation(), explosionPower);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the float to the config as a string and then read it as a string and use `Float.valueOf(String s);` to convert it into a float. Here is an example:

`float explosionPower = Float.valueOf(yourConfig.getString("pathtolong"));`